# "be seen playing" or " be seen to play"?

Tags: grammar

Should I say:

> Jack loves sport. He **is** often **seen playing** basketball on the school playground.

Or?

> Jack loves sport. He **is** often **seen to play** basketball on the school playground.

Which one is correct?
I think both are grammatically correct, but there may be some nuances between the two that I don't comprehend.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, because there are some layers to it. I will come back and write an answer later if I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question because it is not a cut and dried issue.

In American English "seen to do" is no longer in common usage. A lot of American English speakers find this phrase strange or even jarring. The first time I saw it in a book, I also thought it was a mistake. I am under the impression that a British English speaker is more likely to recognize this phrase as valid. I have also read and maybe heard it from older American speakers. But "seen to do something", "seen to represent", "seen to be doing something" are all valid constructions.

This is what the OED has to say about "see (to) do": (italics original; boldface emphasis mine)

> In common with some other verbs of perception (e.g. *hear, notice*), when *see* is used in the **passive** the **infinitive is normally preceded by to (*as they were seen to leave*)**; **when in the active, to is omitted (*as I saw them leave*)**. In early use, however, variation from this is not uncommon (see e.g. quots. a1382, 1542, 1596, a1616).

This construction, "be seen to do", and related constructions such as "be seen doing", "be seen do", etc., all have [aspectial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) significance, and subtle aspectual differences exist between them. Also from the OED:

> Also in common with other verbs of perception, the difference between this construction and that with present participle (see sense 1a(d)) is **aspectual**: **the infinitive indicates that the complete action or event was witnessed** (e.g. *I saw him eat the cake*), whereas **the present participle indicates that the action or event was seen in progress, and may not have been completed or witnessed in its entirety** (e.g. *I saw him eating the cake*, which allows for the possibility that there is some cake left). **In early examples the infinitive is often found where the present participle would now normally be used** (see e.g. quots. a1382, ?1473).

Note the last sentence in that paragraph where the OED says that although there exists a semantic difference between the present participle construction and the infinitive one, in older texts they were used the same way. Personally I find that bit of ambiguity still extant in this usage.

Usually, "he was seen to do something" means the action was witnessed when it was in the process, as @Kate Bunting suggests in a comment.

> He was seen to enter the building.
> =
> He was seen entering the building.

Examples:

> He has been plodding on, visiting for himself, and conversing with, all the persons engaged in this catastrophe, and following up, to its utmost, every gleam of light which might be seen to break in upon it. (*The Suspicions of Mr. Whicher: A Shocking Murder And The Undoing Of A Great Victorian Detective*,  [Kate Summerscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_Summerscale))

> ... an enemy aircraft seen to break off combat in circumstances which lead to the conclusion that it must be a loss although it is not actually seen to crash. (*The Dictionary of Military Terms*, U.S. Department of Defense)

> When, on the other hand, it is the case either that the room lasts for ever, or that the set of persons seen to enter it is without limit, or both these, but at least one person appears to wear shoes of some other colour than black, or no shoes at all, I lose the bet. (*Concepts and Categories*, [Isaiah Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Berlin))

Some variations:

**be seen to be doing something**

> to do something in a way that people will notice, because they want or expect you to do it
> *It’s important that we are seen to be doing something about bullying.* ([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be-seen-to-be-doing-something))

Example:

> Our company needs to be seen to be doing everything for our customers.

**seen to represent**

Example:

> The recent trend is seen to represent an abrupt change in the society.

Comment: so the implication of "be seen to be doing something" is?

Comment: "He was seen to enter the building.
=
He was seen entering the building."  so When in passive voice, there are no differences between using infinitives or present participle, whereas in active voice there are distinctions?

Comment: @mirthspritzsultryobscurantism "be seen to be doing something" means someone does something to show other people that they are doing it. "Our company needs to be seen to be doing everything for our customers." means the company wants its customers to think they are doing everything for the customers. "He was seen to enter the building." means him entering the building was witnessed by other people. And I guess you could say there is a slight difference in the active voice.

Answer (score -1):

Verbs of perception (see, hear, notice, etc.) are used either with the "-ing" form or the infinitive *without* the "to":

Infinitive w/o the "to":  "He heard the bell ring."

-ing form:  "He heard the bell ringing."

but not: "He heard the doorbell to ring."

So, the first one is correct.

Comment: The first one is _better_. It is possible to say "He has been seen to [do something]", but this has more of an implication that he has been caught doing something unusual or surprising.

Comment: I would like to see an example of the second one used anywhere.  It sounds quite awkward to my ear.

Comment: @KateBunting I believe there is a BrE/AmE divide here. Within AmE, there may be regional/generational differences.

Comment: @m_a_s I included some real-world examples in my answer alongside ones I made up.

Comment: @Eddie Kai:  As an older AmE speaker who goes to the UK frequently (until recently...) it still sounds odd.  But thank you for the examples!